# Recreate QMovie upon resizing the widget

Tags: c++, qt

What is the 'proper' way to recreate a `QMovie` widget when it gets resized?

```
class Gif : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QMovie* movie = nullptr;
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

    int widget_width = 0;
    int widget_height = 0;

    Gif(QWidget* parent = 0) : QPushButton(parent) { }



    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* p)
    {
        // Check if the widget has been resized, if so 
        // delete the QLabel/QMovie and recreate them.
        if (widget_width)
        {
            if (widget_width != width())
            {
                QLabel* label = this->findChild<QLabel*>("label");
                label->deleteLater();
                movie->deleteLater();
                movie = nullptr;
            }
        }



        // Load the gif into the QMovie/QLabel.
        if (!movie)
        {
            auto StyleSheet = styleSheet();

            QVector<QString> matches;
            QRegularExpression re(R"(image:\s*url\((.*)\);)");
            QRegularExpressionMatch m = re.match(StyleSheet);

            for (int i = 0; i <= m.lastCapturedIndex(); i++)
                matches.append(m.captured(i));

            movie = new QMovie(matches[1]);
            if (!movie->isValid())
                qDebug() << "failed to create the QMovie.";

            QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
            label->setObjectName("label");

            widget_width = width();
            widget_height = height();

            label->setGeometry(0, 0, widget_width, widget_height);
            label->setMovie(movie);
            label->show();

            movie->setScaledSize(QSize().scaled(widget_width, widget_height, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));
            movie->setSpeed(150);
            movie->start();
        }



        // Pause for 2 seconds after getting into the 
        // last frame.
        if (movie->currentFrameNumber() == (movie->frameCount() -1))
        {
            movie->stop();
            connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(resume()));
            timer->start(2000);
        }


    }


public slots:

    void resume()
    {
        movie->start();
    }
    
};
```

Is it 'safe' to call `deleteLater()` and then assign `movie` to `nullptr`? won't cause any mem leak / UB?

```
                if (widget_width != width())
                {
                    QLabel* label = this->findChild<QLabel*>("label");
                    label->deleteLater();
                    movie->deleteLater();
                    movie = nullptr;
                }
```

Also, is there any alternative to `QMovie` for playing a gif in a gui? it uses a lot of CPU when the gif is medium/high size

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can not offer the answer to your main question.

With your second question, "a lot of CPU usage" when playing QMovie. I found a method to set the CacheMode of QMovie. It will help to reduce the CPU usage of QMovie playing gif.

```
movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheMode.CacheAll)
```